# " Get http://X.X.X.X: no basic auth credentials " error at build-image stage with gitlab ci/cd runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, nexus, gitlab-ci-runner

i have a nexus repository manager with **ip:192.168.253.10** 
that i build and push my docker images into it .
this is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file 
build-image stage :

```
build-image:
  stage: build-image
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
  before_script:
   - git clone http://192.168.251.80/public-group/devops.git
   - cp -Rv devops/DevOps/src/main/docker/app-scripts src/main/docker/
   - cp -v devops/DevOps/src/main/docker/itext-4.2.0.jar target/$App_Name/WEB-INF/lib
  script:
        - cp -R target/$App_Name src/main/docker/
        - cd src/main/docker
        - docker rm -f $App_Name || true
        - docker rmi -f 192.168.253.10/$App_Name:latest || true
        - docker build -t 192.168.253.10/$App_Name:latest .

  tags:
   - shell
```

this stage use a runner with shell executer

***192.168.251.80*** is my gitlab server
and my gitlab-runner registered and installed on ***192.168.253.75***

after running this stage i got an error like this :

```
$ docker build -t 192.168.253.10/$App_Name:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  189.3MB

Step 1/8 : FROM 192.168.253.10/ahg-img-weblogic:v3
Get http://192.168.253.10/v2/ahg-img-weblogic/manifests/v3: no basic auth credentials
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

i logged in to my nexus server with 
`docker login 192.168.253.10`
and set my nexus server to the `insecure registry` in my gitlab-runner server ***192.168.253.75***

i don't know what other things should i do to fix this error 
any idea ?

Comment: I suppose you need to enter the user and password no matter of it is secure or insecure connection . The default one on a nexus -> https://help.sonatype.com/learning/repository-manager-3/first-time-installation-and-setup/lesson-1%3A--installing-and-starting-nexus-repository-manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this error, it seems you are not logged in your private docker registry. first check your logging status, if you are logged in and the problem has not been resolve, check your User!
sometimes a User is calling command remotely like CI/CD scripts, and this User is not the same User that is logged in.